# Dynamics crm: change text direction with javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Any tips how to change text direction with Javascript (only text direction not language) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for any one who will have same need, use code below in Javscript :

```
document.getElementById("new_message").style.textAlign="right";
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from your question you could be something like that

```
var a = "foo";
var b = new String();
for(i = (a.length-1); i >= 0; i--){
    b += a[i];
}
console.log(b);
```

//b now is string oof

Comment: what i need is to change text direction "rtl" to "ltr" with javascript for a text field in dynamics crm 2011